# android setScrollX with animation

Tags: android, scroll, android-imageview

There are methods in `ImageView` called `setScrollX` (`imageView.setScrollX(float x);`) and `setScrollY`. They set the scrolls without any animation. How can I set scroll with animation?

There is no need to say this, but I can mention that I scaled the `ImageView` and know I want to scroll in it.

Answer (score 0):

set translate animation to imageview

```html
private Animation           translateAnimation;
image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourimage);

translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f, TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 100f, TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f, TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f);
translateAnimation.setDuration(10000);
translateAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1);
translateAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
translateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
image.setAnimation(_translateAnimation);
```